# How do I get JavaScript Values from Selenium?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I am running the following code (Java selenium client)- PAGE_NUMBER has a value, but I am unable to get it using selenium:

```
String script = "var cellValue = selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().PAGE_NUMBER;";
selenium.runScript(script);

String value = selenium.getEval("selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().cellValue;");
System.out.println("Value: " + value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Selenium 1 at all and Selenium2/Webdriver is very different. However there are three things that I suspect to play a role in this issue:

1. Scope: You declared the variable as local to the scope of the script (by writing `var`). You might try using a global variable by omitting the `var` keyword, so that you can access it later.
2. Why do you try to access the variable via `selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().`. Try omitting this part.
3. The semicolon after cellValue is probably no good idea either

And then again, why not simply using

```
String value = selenium.getEval("selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().PAGE_NUMBER");
```

?

I hope at least some part of this answer helps you. As I said I am just guessing.